# App cannot pass values between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on an app in which the user inputs a number into one activity, and the number shows up on the next activity. This is what I have so far.

First activity: `EnterText.java`

```
public class EnterText extends Activity {

    //This is the string that will be passed to the next activity
    public static String mynumber = "com.example.ListviewExplorer.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_text);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.enter_text, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //This is where onClick, the button will invoke sendMessage
    //sendMessage is supposed to start the next activity
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayText.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mynumber = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("MyNumber",mynumber);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Second activity: `DisplayText.java`

```
public class DisplayText extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String mynumber = extras.getString("MyNumber");
        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textview.setText(EnterText.mynumber);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_text);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this app crashes when I press the button on the first activity and it calls sendMessage; the second activity isn't even displayed.

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

`LogCat` is posted below.

Get to it!

```
05-29 11:57:59.385: W/dalvikvm(3046): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42d5d140)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046): Process: com.example.listviewexplorer, PID: 3046
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewexplorer/com.example.listviewexplorer.DisplayText}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at com.example.listviewexplorer.DisplayText.onCreate(DisplayText.java:21)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-29 11:57:59.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3046):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the layout before using it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // assign layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_text);
    // then you can use it
    TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textview.setText(EnterText.mynumber);
    ...
}
```

Since the layout has not been defined it is at that stage `null` and when you try to access Views inside it you get that `NullPointerException` thrown.

Comment: Good call! I'll accept your answer when the time restriction is up

Comment: Thanks. You should give laalto's answer an upvote too and consider it for acceptance as we answered similarly at the same same. Accept which ever is clearer to you or seems to help the most.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText(EnterText.mynumber);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_text);
```

Before `setContentView()` `findViewById()` will return null no matter what, and invoking a method on null reference causes the NPE as seen in your stacktrace.

Move the `setContentView()` above the `findViewById()`, assuming that `textView1` is actually in `activity_display_text` layout.

This fixes the NPE crash. To actually pass a value, have a look at some of the other answers.